# Showing a Vector field is irrotational, given it has zero flux through the surface, zero divergance, and a zero laplacian.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

I'm struggling to prove the following:
Given a volume $V$ bounded by a closed surface $S$, a vector $\bar{F}$ satisfies the following:
$$\nabla \cdot \bar{F} = 0$$
$$\nabla^2 \bar{F} = \bar{0}$$
and the flux of $\bar{F} \times (\nabla \times \bar{F})$ through $S$ is zero.

Then there exists $\phi \in V$  such that $\bar{F} = \nabla \phi$.

<strike>I understand that this is equivalent to proving that $\bar{F}$ has zero curl, as the region is clearly simply connected.</strike>

Is there a clever application of Green's theorem that I am missing?

Comment: Why would the region $V$ be simply connected? For example if $S$ is a torus, the region $V$ inside is not simply connected as it is a solid torus.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'll edit my question.